# Matlab histogram getting BinCenter and BinEdges

Tags: matlab

Assume I have and 'Figure 1' window includes a histogram graph. I want to get values of BinCenter and BinEdges and assign those values to array1 and array2. 
Have you any idea?

Comment: Which MATALB version are you using? Where did this window come from? Did you open a `.fig`/`.mat` file?

Comment: 2013a version and comes from script

Answer (score 2):

### For HG2 with `histogram`

First get a handle to the histogram object, either with

```
h = get(gca, 'Children');
```

or clicking on the histogram and using

```
h = gco;
```

You can then inspect the object properties. For example, the bin edges are in `h.BinEdges`:

```
array1 = h.BinEdges;
```

The centers are not a property of the histogram, but you can just average consecutive edges:

```
array2 = conv(array1, [.5 .5], 'valid');
```

or

```
array2 = (array1(1:end-1)+array1(2:end))/2;
```

or, in recent Matlab versions,

```
array2 = movmean(array1, 2, 'Endpoints', 'discard');
```

### For the old graphics system with `histc`

The data is in `'Vertices'` property. This is a matrix. Its first column contains the values of the edges. You will have to process them manually.

```
h = get(gca, 'Children');
v = get(h, 'Vertices');
edges = v(:,1);
```